# Passing lambda functions to other methods

Tags: c++, lambda

Do lambda function have a signature so that I can pass them around?

```
template<class Fn> 
HRESULT foreach(Fn _fuction)
{

}


object->foreach(
    [param1, param2] (int item) 
    {
    }
);

object->foreach(
    [param1, param2, param3] (int item) 
    {
    }
);
```

I want to use a typedef function instead of templates, I think the type of the function will strict the formal parameters but will allow captured list to vary.

can I use typedef instead of templates to pass lambda functions around?

something like:

```
typedef void (*Fn)(int);
```

but allows lambda not function pointer.

I tried using std::fuction but seems not working.

Comment: For what it's worth, using a template type isn't a bad solution (depending on context, of course) since there is some overhead involved in converting to `function`.

Comment: I swear this exact question was asked like a couple days ago.

Comment: Oh, [there it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191130/typedef-for-lambda-functions).

Comment: Can you show how you tried using `std::function`? *seems not working* isn't a particularly useful description.

Answer (score 1):

> The type of the *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a **unique**, unnamed non-
>   union class type — called the *closure type* ...

(C++11 §5.1.2/3, emphasis mine)

My reading of this is that even if two lambda-expressions have the same parameter list, return type, and capture list, they nevertheless have different types.

```
auto f = []{};
typedef decltype(f) lambda_type;
void g(lambda_type lambda) { lambda(); }
int main() {
    g(f);    // OK
    g([]{}); // error: type mismatch
}
```

So no, what you are trying to do cannot be done. As others have suggested, try using `std::function`, or retain the template (what's wrong with templates, anyway?)

Answer (score 0):

The actual type of a lambda is unspecified. But they are convertible to `function`; in your case, `std::function<void(int)>` (`void` is the return type, the parameter types go in the parentheses).

Comment: yes I tried that seems not working, what header should I include?

Comment: The header is `<functional>`